# Contents of NSMutableArray being released during call to tableVIew:makeViewWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nstableview

Writing an ARC Mavericks app, I've got an instance variable NSMUtableArray, `venueArray` to which I am assigning a an array of Foursquare venues returned via the fabulous [VenueKit](https://github.com/logancollins/VenueKit). After I save the returned results into `venueArray`, I reload the an `NSTableView`. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)searchChanged:(id)sender {
    NSString *searchString=[_searchField stringValue];
    VNKVenueSearch *fsSearch=[[VNKVenueSearch alloc] initWithService:_fourSquare];
    [fsSearch setMaximumNumberOfResults:20];
    [fsSearch setNaturalLanguageQuery:searchString];
    [fsSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *venues, NSError *error) {
        [_searchField hideProgressIndicator];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (venues) {
                [self processResults:venues];
            }
        });
    }];
}
-(void) processResults:(NSArray*) venues{
    if (!venueArray)
        venueArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    [venueArray removeAllObjects];
    [venueArray addObjectsFromArray:venues];
    [_locationsTable reloadData];
}
```

And my table and datasource delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [venueArray count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[venueArray count]); //<==============
    // Here we get the expected answer (20)

    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"LocationName" owner:self];

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[venueArray count]); //<============
    // Here we get 0!
    if ([venueArray count] > 0) // I put this in to avoid a crash cause of empty array
        result.textField.stringValue = ((VNKVenue*)[venueArray objectAtIndex:row]).name;

    return result;

}
```

I know the array is being emptied during `tableView:makeViewWithIdentifier` view creation because the NEXT time I invoke the callout and the ensuing table reload, everything works great. That's because `tableView:makeViewWithIdentifier` is merely dequeueing existing views, rather than creating new ones.

And I know the `VNKVenue` contents of the array are being released, because I overrode `dealloc` in `VNKVenue`, and logged the fact that they were, indeed, being dealloced.

Originally I was populating `venueArray` in the same thread as the callout handler, and when that failed, I moved it to the main thread, as implemented above. Both fail.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Are you maintaining a strong reference to the array?  (ie `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *venueArray;`)?

Comment: Also, your line "I put this in to avoid a crash cause of empty array" is unnecessary once you fix this, because the method will never get called unless `numberOfRowsInTableView:` returns `> 0`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ARC is deallocating your array because you aren't maintaining a strong reference to it.

You may be able to access it in `numberOfRowsInTableView:` because the autorelease pool has not drained yet (ie, you're still on the same run loop).

To resolve, just maintain a `strong` reference:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *venueArray;
```

Then, either `@synthesize venueArray;` or change your `venueArray` references to `self.venueArray`.

Now, the array will not be deallocated until this property is set to `nil` or the owner is deallocated.

Comment: I was previously declaring the `venueArray` ivar inside the interface and not making a property for it. Switched to an interface block inside the .m, with `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *venueArray;`, and the problem remains unchanged.

Comment: I wonder if you're running into issues because you're creating a new request for every character typed in the search field.  Perhaps you should keep a reference to `fsSearch`, and call `[fsSearch cancel]` on the old search object when another character is typed.

Comment: If that's the issue, `[fsSearch cancel]` won't totally fix it, but it might make it happen *less*.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in a related question that SO suggested. Turns out that `awakeFromNib` (where I was initializing my array) is called during each `tableView:makeViewWithIdentifier` that results in a new view. Odd.

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556165/calling-makeviewwithidentifierowner-causes-arc-to-re-create-ivar?rq=1)